# NSDateFormatter doesn't parse my string

Tags: nsdateformatter

I've got this kind of date: `Sun, 30 Jun 2013 16:00:00`

I've created this NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

but when I use it with dateFromString it returns nil.

What's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this fix it? (Maybe your device is in a locale that doesn't understand Sun or Jun)

```
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

Comment: Yes you are right, infact on the simulator all works (english language) the problem was on my iPad (italian language) Thank you!